# I got incorrect calculations in save method Django

Tags: python, django

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField('Цена', decimal_places=2, max_digits=9)

class Discount(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Товар', related_name='discount')
    discount_price = models.DecimalField('Скидочная цена', decimal_places=2, max_digits=9, blank=True, null=True)
    discount_percent = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Процент скидки (число)', blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.discount_percent and not self.discount_price:
            raise ValueError('Заполните хотя бы одно поле: процент или скидочная цена')

        if not self.discount_percent:
            self.discount_percent = (self.discount_price // self.product.price) * 100
        elif not self.discount_price:
            self.discount_price = (self.product.price * self.discount_percent) // 100

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I write in admin panel discount_percent without discount_price calculation will be correct. I get really a discount price.
But when I write discount_price without discount_percent, Discount_percent always has a value of 0
[image: Screen from the admin]

When I added a lot of prints, all input data were correct but calculations not.
How i can solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the code is in this line:

```
self.discount_percent = (self.discount_price // self.product.price) * 100
```

In this line, you're using floor division. You need to use normal division instead. For example 3//5 = 0 and 100 // 105 = 0. Anytime the number on the left is larger than the right, since it is floored, it will be equal to 0. Edit the line to say this:

```
self.discount_percent = (self.discount_price / self.product.price) * 100
```

The calculations should then work as follows: (3/5) * 100 = 60.0
If this needs to be an integer, you can just wrap it with `int()`